# Deciphering a DC jack schematic

Tags: power, schematics, connector

I am trying to include a DC jack on one of my PCBs. I am just setting up the footprints now, and I am not quite sure which pin is which. What do the symbols on the drawing mean?

I have included a snap of the schematic below, it has been taken directly from the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/457135.pdf).

[image: DC jack schematic]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pin 3 is the center pin, pin one connects to the barrel and pin 2 is used
to detect if there is a plug inserted. The lower left drawing shows the physical
pins looking at the bottom side.

Answer (score 24):

It's a visual representation of how the socket works.

- Pin 3 represents the pin that mates with the center of the plug (typically V+)
- Pin 1 is the sprung contact that connects to the outside of the plug (typically Gnd)
- Pin 2 contacts to Pin 1 (Gnd) but breaks contact when the plug is inserted (as the Pin 1 contact springs away)

Answer (score 11):

While this is resurrected due to Endolith's retagging, I want to clarify the reason that Pin 2 connects to the shield of the jack, but only when there's no plug inserted.  You can do one of three things to wire this correctly:

1. Only connect to pin 1.
2. Connect pins 1 and 2 together.
3. Connect pin 1 to your circuit's ground node, and connect pin 2 to another power connector (Black binding post for a banana jack, or battery ground terminal, for example.) Then, you can connect pin 3 to a red binding post or battery positive terminal, and have 2 power supplies without worrying about output contention.

Method 3 is the reason that these plugs are designed the way they are.

Comment: Situation 3 is for the case when you have a circuit that can run off of battery power or a plug in (wall wart) style source right? Pin 2 is connected to pin 1 when power source is not plugged in so the battery can use pin 2 as ground. When the plug is inserted the battery is disconnected from ground so only the plug is providing power. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I generally connect pins 1 and 2 together.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all! (Yet oddly had 2 upvotes)

Comment: Why doesn't it answer the question? It's in addition to the other answers, as it's often done. One other person mentioned it, after I did.