# Schematic symbol for DC barrel jack - and plug?

Tags: power, connector, schematics

If I go along the definitions in [What is the difference between a connector, jack, plug, and port?](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001379.htm):

> The **plug** is part of a cable that connects to a port. The plug always connects to something else (e.g., a jack or port).
>   A **jack** is similar to a port and is a hole or other connection that allows a compatible plug to be connected to the jack.

... then in this image (found [here](https://ng.jumia.is/-TficLry2lznW6cSj9qaGpAnllQ=/fit-in/500x500/filters:fill(white)/product/03/47187/1.jpg?1116) via image search):

[image]

... I'd call the things on the left DC (barrel) plugs (or "male" connectors) - and the things on the right would be DC (barrel) jacks (or "female" connectors). Would this be a correct nomenclature (even if I'm aware conventions like these are not strictly followed in the market)?

That being said, I'm aware there is a schematic symbol for DC (barrel) jacks - like this one, taken from [Deciphering a DC jack schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/deciphering-a-dc-jack-schematic):

[image]

My question is: is there a schematic symbol specifically for DC (barrel) *plugs*, and if so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Normally power connectors have the type of power defined on a schematic. You cannot assume AC or DC without testing or having the schematic. The same applies to what voltage might be there, grounding, etc.

EDIT: There is no plug or socket I know of that is implicitly AC or DC by its shape alone. It must be defined in the schematic or a block diagram if no place else. The builder has the option to silkscreen it on the case next to the socket, which you will see on many wall-warts and desktop power supplies.

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky256 - I'm aware I cannot assume AC or DC without the schematic; I was just wondering is there a specific way to represent DC plug as a symbol on a schematic, like there is for the DC jack (else, as a worst case, one can always just represent it with two terminating "pins" on a schematic, I guess)

Comment: Unless you manually create your own symbols, along with the PCB footprint, you are stuck with the limited amount stored in your parts library. No surprise. With Orcad I had to create hundreds of custom switches and plugs for my own use. It is neither AC or DC until you note it on the schematic.